# play multiple audio files sequentially

Tags: html, mobile, html5-audio

I can play audio html5 elements in mobile browsers after onClick events - this works just fine. But my animation got more than 1 audio element and I want them to one after another.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Animation? You should illustrate more clearly what you want to achieve.